# hadoop DistributedCache returns null

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, distributed-cache

i'm using hadoop DistributedCache,but i got some troubles.
my hadoop is in pseudo-distributed mode.

[from here we can see in pseudo-distributed mode we use 
DistributedCache.getLocalCache(xx) to retrive cached file.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201007.mbox/%3C651981.45757.qm@web46311.mail.sp1.yahoo.com%3E)

first i put my file into DistributedCache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(
"hdfs://localhost:8022/user/administrator/myfile").toUri(),
            job.getConfiguration());
```

then retrieve in mapper setup(),but `DistributedCache.getLocalCache` returns null.i can see my cached file through

`System.out.println("Cache: "+context.getConfiguration().get("mapred.cache.files"));`

and it print out:

`hdfs://localhost:8022/user/administrator/myfile`

here is my Pseudocode:

```
public static class JoinMapper{
     @Override
protected void setup(Context context){
        Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context
                .getConfiguration());
    System.out.println("Cache 
             :"+context.getConfiguration().get("mapred.cache.files"));
      Path cacheFile;
      if (cacheFiles != null) {}
    }
}

xx....

public static void main(String[] args){
             Job job = new Job(conf, "Join Test");
        DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("hdfs://localhost:8022/user/administrator/myfile").toUri(),
            job.getConfiguration());}
```

sorry about poor Typesetting.anyone help please....

btw,i can get uris using

`URI[] uris = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(context
                        .getConfiguration());`

uris returns :
hdfs://localhost:8022/user/administrator/myfile

when i try to read from uri,error with file not found exception.

Comment: try this : `DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("user/administrator/myfile").toUri(),
            job.getConfiguration());`

Comment: it turns out filenotfound exception...

Comment: Try [this](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-load-file-in-distributedcache-in.html)

Answer (score -1):

The Distributed Cache will copy your files from HDFS to the local file system of all TaskTracker. 
How are u reading the file? If the file is in HDFS u will have to get HDFS FileSystem, otherwise it is going to use the default (probably the local one). So to read the file in HDFS try:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Path("hdfs://localhost:8022/user/administrator/myfile").toUri(), new Configuration());
Path path = new Path (url);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));
```